# You cannot use different slug names for the same dynamic pat

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to `npm run build` on `nextjs` project but give me this error:

> you cannot use different slug names for the same dynamic path ('category' !== 'slug')

[image]

This my page directory:

[image]

Any idea what's wrong? I don't have a duplicate slug name even!